# Why the loop will fall into infinite loop when typing characters

Tags: c

This is a wrong code.
One of the wrong questions is that the program will fall into an infinite loop when typing characters.
Please ignore the other errors that exist in the code,just focusing on the problem that characters cause an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x1, x2;
  do{
    printf("Input x1, x2:");
    scanf("%d,%d", &x1, &x2);
  }while (x1 * x2 > 0);
  printf("x1=%d,x2=%d\n", x1, x2);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the program will fall into an infinite loop when typing characters.

when you do not enter a valid number for a `scanf %d` the wrong input is not removed, so if you do nothing you will get it again the next `scanf %d`

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x1, x2;
  do{
    printf("Input x1, x2:");

    if (scanf("%d,%d", &x1, &x2) != 2) {
      char * lineptr = NULL;
      size_t n = 0;
      ssize_t r = getline(&lineptr, &n, stdin); /* flush input */

      if (r == -1)
        /* EOF */
        return -1;

      free(lineptr);
    }
  } while (x1 * x2 > 0);
  printf("x1=%d,x2=%d\n", x1, x2);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra c.c
/tmp % ./a.out
Input x1, x2:1,2
Input x1, x2:a
Input x1, x2:1,a
Input x1, x2:1 2
Input x1, x2:0,1
x1=0,x2=1
```

---

(edit)

if you just want to stop the loop in case of an error :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x1, x2;
  int ok = 1;

  do{
    printf("Input x1, x2:");

    if (scanf("%d,%d", &x1, &x2) != 2) {
      ok = 0;
      break;
    }
  } while ((x1 * x2) > 0);

  if (ok)
    printf("x1=%d,x2=%d\n", x1, x2);

  return 0;
}
```

or finishing all the execution on error

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x1, x2;

  do{
    printf("Input x1, x2:");

    if (scanf("%d,%d", &x1, &x2) != 2)
      return 0;
  } while ((x1 * x2) > 0);

  printf("x1=%d,x2=%d\n", x1, x2);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra c.c
/tmp % ./a.out
Input x1, x2:1,2
Input x1, x2:1,0
x1=1,x2=0
/tmp % ./a.out
Input x1, x2:1,,
/tmp %
```

Comment: so how should I modify the code to remove the input in the buffer ?Please note that I just want to remove the input in the buffer so that the program could stop the loop

Comment: @MMJJQQ a first possibility is to stop immediately in case of an error so `if(scanf(...) != 2) break;` but the _printf_ after will print may be uninitialized values. When you do input it is 'gentle' to allow error ;-) Note : useless to try `fflush(stdin);` that does not clear the input. BTW I just see I did 2 errors (was in urge to go to lunch ^^), I edited my answer. The way I use the clear the wrong input is the more secure one

Comment: @MMJJQQ you can also do `char s[32]; if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) == NULL) /* EOF */ return -1;` but you suppose the line is smaller than 20 etc. _getline_ doesn't make assumption and works

Comment: @MMJJQQ I edited my answer with alternative stopping the loop/execution on error